# Django downloading image using ImageField

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a Django app that allows user to upload and download images from `/images/` folder (similar to a static folder in my app). My **upload** part of the app uses ImageField to store the image filepath into MySQL database:

**models.py**

```
class ImagefieldModel(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200) 
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to = "images/")

    class Meta:
        db_table = "imageupload"
```

**forms.py**

```
class ImagefieldForm(forms.Form): 
    name = forms.CharField() 
    image_field = forms.ImageField()
```

**fileupload.html**

```
{% extends "main/header.html" %}
 

 {% block content %}
      <head>
        <title>Django File Upload</title>
      </head>
      <body>
          <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
              {% csrf_token %} 
              {{ form.as_p }} 
              <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
          </form> 
      </body>
 {% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
def imgupload(request): 
    context = {}
    if request.method == "POST": 
        form = ImagefieldForm(request.POST, request.FILES) 
        if form.is_valid(): 
            name = form.cleaned_data.get("name") 
            img = form.cleaned_data.get("image_field") 
            obj = ImagefieldModel.objects.create( 
                                 title = name,  
                                 img = img 
                                 ) 
            obj.save() 
            print(obj)
            messages.info(request, f"image uploaded successfully!")
            return redirect("main:basehome")
    else: 
        form = ImagefieldForm()
        context['form'] = form
        return render( request, "main/fileupload.html", context)
```

For the **download** part of my app, I want the app to list down all images from the `/image/` folder and users can choose an image to download into their download folder. How do I do that in Django while using ImageField?

Comment: What's the syntax error you're getting now?

Comment: @markwalker_ I managed to find another alternative. I just use the "ImagefieldModel.objects.all()" to get all the images to display from the file, then right click to "download" the image. Though would be good if there was a way to download image files.by users clicking on the download button to download a specific image.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to add the image to the response object. Something like;

```py
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        # first get the instance of your model from the database
        imagefieldinstance = self.get_object()

        # Then get the URL of the image to download
        url = imagefieldinstance.img.url
        try:
            # Download the image to the server
            img = requests.get(url)
            if not 200 <= img.status_code < 400:
                raise Http404()

        except Exception as e:
            raise Http404() from e

        # Figure out the mimetype of the file
        mime_type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(url)

        # Get the file extension
        _, extension = os.path.splitext(url.split('/')[-1])

        # Create the filename of the download
        filename = '{}{}'.format(
            slugify(imagefieldinstance.title),
            extension
        )

        # Add the content of the (image) file to the response object
        response = HttpResponse(
            img.content,
            content_type=mime_type
        )
        response['Content-Disposition'] = \
            'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(filename)

        # Send the user the response
        return response
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.. Can you please explain what each part of the code does? I'm still new to Django

Comment: @Reallynoobatprogramming I have added comments.

Comment: I have encountered an error using your suggested codes as shown in my answer below. Can you help me to fix it please? Also can you guide me on what parts that are needed to be modified to suit my download part of my system? Also I removed some sections like the "raise Http404()" to avoid any errors as Im doing it in a development environment. Your help is much appreciated

Comment: Maybe it would be better if I can have an alternative way to contact you for this? Discord or something where I can show you the code and you can help me debug on the fly. I am short of time to finish my system and this download thing is the only section stopping me.

Comment: If you've got a new problem you can't resolve, ask another question